# Remove Overlap Time in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008, overlap

I've been asked to make a **sql server query** where I need to remove the **Overlap time period** between the service tickets. Like we have a service which is facing 3 different issues at a similar time. The name of the table is **ticket** and it has n-number of tickets in it, out of which I am interested in these 3 since they belong to the same service.

`Ticket Number    Start Time    End Time 
    1               11:00         15:00
    2               12:00         13:00
    3               14:00         16:00`

I needed a **query to calculate the total downtime during these tickets were active**, which is 6 hours (11:00-16:00).

What to do ?

Comment: SUM(end-time - start-time) ... (perhaps a group by too)

Comment: Not working. It shows SUM doesn't work on datetime datatype

Comment: You have to get interval datatype somehow, check documentation!

Comment: I am able to get the difference in start time and end time of those tickets by using DATEDIFF. But i need to remove the overlap of time

Comment: So you can't do SUM(datediff)?

Comment: This should do resolve your problem: SELECT DATEDIFF(HOUR, '11:00','16:00') TotalHours

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use DATEDIFF and SUM functions together:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(HOUR, MIN([Start Time]),MAX([End Time]))AS [total downtime]  
FROM tblTicketTable 
WHERE [Ticket Number] = 1 OR [Ticket Number] = 2 OR [Ticket Number] = 3
```

Comment: it gives me the total downtime which is **Overlapping**

Ticket 1 is 4 hours, Ticket 2 is 1 hour, Ticket 3 is 2 hours. Agreed. If we calculate it separately, each ticket took 7 hours in total. But in a day the service was down from 11:00 till 16:00 which is 5 hours.

I hope you are getting my point

Comment: The query will produce an incorrect result when there are gaps between any of the ranges where they do not adjoin or overlap (multiple separate outages throughout a day). For example, if ticket 1 was in effect from 08:00 to 10:00 instead of 11:00-15:00, the query would incorrectly count the two hour gap between 10:00 (the end of ticket 1) and 12:00 (the start time of ticket 2) as part of the outage. If your groups of tickets will only ever involve a single prolonged outage, then this isn't a problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you build a table ( or view, or UDF, or Cartesian join, or recursive CTE) that generates all 1440 times in a day at minute-level granularity {00:00..23:59}, you can join your tickets against it and use the count of individual minutes to calculate the ticket's duration. When a group of tickets are involved, count the number of distinct minutes to avoid double-counting minutes in any overlapping ranges.

This example assumes (as does your sample data) that the time range on a ticket must begin and end on the same calendar day, without crossing midnight into another day. If a ticket can span more than one calendar day, then you'll also need a table or expression containing the dates involved so they can participate in the join.

```
SELECT COUNT( DISTINCT t.ticketnumber ) AS ticketcount,
    COUNT( DISTINCT m.timeval ) AS  totalminutes
FROM ticketTbl t
INNER JOIN timeList m
ON t.startTime <= m.timeval
AND t.endTime > m.timeval
WHERE t.ticketnumber IN ( 1, 2, 3 )
;
```